# jQuery autocomplete is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <form method="POST" id="id1">
        <input id="id2" type="text" style="min-width: 370px;" class="form-control" placeholder="...">
    </form>
</div>
```

And this correctly triggers the following ajax events:

```
   $("#id1").on("click", function(event, ui) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/id1",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.Data); // ["a", "b", "c"]
                    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(data.Data, extractLast(request.term)));
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function() {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And I even checked that it correctly prints out the values with `["a", "b", "c"]` but it just doesn't show in web page.

Does anybody know if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: For request term, I am getting `Object {term: "↵                                ↵                            "}`

Comment: method="POST" in form and type: "GET" in ajax?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it is not being posted nor getted as it's the event handler that will launch this.  And besides that, they have got nothing to do with eachother, the GET is an XHR ajax call that gets json.  the POST can still be used once the autocomplete fills out the field, a post action can do something else with that content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like it can't parse your `request.term` correctly due to wrong selector for autocomplete itself - `$("#id1").on("click" ...` which is form (not an input).

Your input id is `id2`, so just replace it and everything should work.

Comment: I am getting `Object {term: "↵                                ↵                            "}`

Comment: It will not work when doing so, the event is never fired